# Pagination gets "stuck"?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple table application that displays dummy data with columns like name, number, date, etc. You can sort it by columns, and it is paginated.

However, when I use the pagination, some of the rows get stuck at the top. It kind of gets sorted alphabetically by the column I intended, but when the page changes (pretend page 4), the rows *underneath* the first few top rows change, while the very top rows don't budge.

[Here is a functional plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/3nlpCdZPotzoeGCnYlQE)

HTML:

```
 <pagination class="pagination pagination-sm" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
   <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in keys" ng-click="sorting.predicate=key;">
        {{key}}
      </th>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="row in data | startFrom:currentRow | orderBy:sorting.predicate:sorting.reverse | limitTo:itemsPerPage">
        <td ng-repeat="key in keys">
          {{row[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Angular:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});

    $scope.data = [{
        "id": 0,
        "age": 30,
        "name": "Trina Pace",
        "gender": "female",
        "email": "trinapace@darwinium.com",
        "phone": "+1 (874) 414-2654"
    },etc..];

    $scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.data[0]);
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.data.length;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 25;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.currentRow = 0;

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
      $scope.currentRow = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
      console.log('current row: ' + $scope.currentRow);
      console.log('items per page: ' + $scope.itemsPerPage);
    };

    $scope.sorting = {predicate:'name',reverse:false};
```

Am I missing, and/or doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I gave all the empty names values, and still see odd behavior.  Are you sure you didn't change something else at the same time?

Comment: It looks like the problem wasn't the nulls. Updated my question above. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `startFrom:currentRow` to after `orderBy:sorting.predicate:sorting.reverse`.

You want to filter *after* you sort.

Comment: Simple mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/7BbgJ4TMU0pSY8gyDLef?p=preview

```
<table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in keys" ng-click="sorting.predicate=key;">
        {{key}}
      </th>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="row in data |  orderBy:sorting.predicate:sorting.reverse | startFrom:currentRow | limitTo:itemsPerPage">
        <td ng-repeat="key in keys">
          {{row[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Phil Sandler beat you by a minute ;)

Comment: less then minute, life is hard :)